# How can Flocking Algorithms be used in GIS?

Tags: algorithm, gis-principle

The first flocking algorithm was written by [Craig Reynolds](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/) in 1986. A recent browser implementation can be found [here](http://harry.me/2011/02/17/neat-algorithms---flocking).

[image: flock of seagulls]

The notes refer to "*The use of Flocks to drive a Geographic Analysis Machine*" (1998) by James Macgill and Stan Openshaw which

> uses a flock model, with communication
>   between boids, to better search for
>   clusters in spacial datasets, just as
>   a natural flock provides better
>   foraging than individual birds could
>   manage.

What other real world examples of this algorithm have been used in GIS, and do any GIS applications implement this functionality?

Comment: It seems like the fast growing field of sensor-equipped robots might use this.  Maybe a [flock of robots](http://www.ndep.us/A-Flock-of-Robots) for [robotic mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotic_mapping).

Comment: The Macgill and Openshaw paper is at http://www.geocomputation.org/1998/24/gc24_01.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, implementations of ABM are written in agent-based environments, most of which aren't full fledged GIS systems but may be able to use GIS data. One of the challenges of incorporating these kinds of models into a GIS is their strong temporal aspect: each agent is changing over time in response to surrounding agents. Because a typical GIS focuses on vector and raster data, its a fairly different data model.

There is [Agent Analyst](http://www.spatial.redlands.edu/agentanalyst/) which runs within ArcGIS and is due for a update to 10 in the near future, or you can take a look at the [ABM packages listed on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_agent-based_modeling_software). [Netlogo](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/) has a GIS extension which can be used to interact with spatial data, and a recent [Netlogo-R](http://evolvingspaces.blogspot.com/2010/03/netlogo-r-extension.html) bridge may give you added flexibility in the spatial component of the analysis. Netlogo is nice to experiment with because it provides a graphical environment for exploring the model, including shareable Java applets, such as [this one for flocking](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/Flocking).

Check out this recent [implementation of flocking](http://harry.me/2011/02/17/neat-algorithms---flocking) which walks through the code very clearly, neat stuff!

Comment: Very nice summary of options available. It was that last example that got my interest.

Answer (score 10):

It seems that you are looking for examples of Agent-based Modeling (ABM). There are many GIS models adopt the ABM mechanism. For example, urban planning used lots of cellular automata models that are essentially same as the flocking model. I have implemented a ABM for U.S. logistics industry using AnyLogic to detect the dynamic organizational structure for supply chain providers and users.

Comment: Thanks. Using the ABM terminology rather than flocking reveals a vast wealth of information such as this blog - http://gisagents.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 5):

James Macgill, Stan Openshaw and I did some more work on cluster detection using flocking boids back in 1999 http://www.geocomputation.org/1999/069/gc_069.htm. This seems to have been followed up by Gianluigi Folino http://staff.icar.cnr.it/folino/papers/ppsn02.pdf. There is also Jameson Conley's work  who was a student of James.